# Waking a sleeping thread on demand

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a servant thread that I want to do a task whenever my master thread tells it to do the task.

Here is the run method in my servant thread:

```
public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Servant woke up.");
            for (int i = 0; i < globalVariable; i++) {
                System.out.println("Servant is working very hard.");
            }
            try {
                System.out.println("Servant went to sleep.");
                //I want servant to sleep until master wakes it up so I picked a big number
                Thread.sleep(999999999);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Servant had a hard time falling asleep");
            }
        }
    }
```

So when my master thread does this:

```
globalVariable = 10;
servant.interrupt();
```

I expect my servant to say it woke up, work 10 times as hard, and then fall back asleep, but right now it doesn't do anything, nothing gets printed on the console except an initial "Servant woke up." and "Servant went to sleep."

(I am very new to threading, so sorry if this is pretty basic)

Comment: If it prints nothing, you're not running the thread. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, make sure that `globalVariable` is volatile. If you haven't already, I strongly encourage you to read a high-quality, in-depth tutorial -- or even pick up a book (Java Concurrency In Practice is often recommended). Concurrency is hard, and it's almost impossible to learn by poking around and trying things out. If you do that, you're likely to write code that will work 95% of the time, but then fail at the worst time, and infrequently enough that it's very hard to debug.

Comment: Is anything printed if you omit the interrupt?

Comment: You must call servant.start() to start the servant thread. Did you call it?

Comment: Ah sorry, I should not have said the console is empty, there is an initial "Servant woke up." and "Servant went to sleep.", but nothing gets added to the console when the servant.interupt() is called.  I did not know this would be so complicated with volatile variables(have not heard of those) and concurrency, so I think I might forego this project until I learn more java.  Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at a `ReentrantLock` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

This lets you create a `Condition` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) by calling the `newCondition()` method.
This Condition lets you `await()` and `signal()` your Threads to inform them something special has happenend in your program.